# Android SIP API - Receive Incoming Call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, asterisk, sip, voip

I creating softphone application using Android SIP API (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip) and I have successfully registered to my Asterisk server and I can call another peer on another softphone. I can hear voice on both sides and everything works perfect.

Now, I have problem receiving call from another softphone. onRinging method is never executed. On the other softphone I am getting status RINGING, but in my app that call is never received.

I have created IncomingCallReceiver class and also WalkieTalkieActivity, but none of them is doing its job (most probably I am doing something wrong, or I did not initiate some of them, or call or whatever...).

I am stuck on receiving the calls. Also the official documentation is not clear to me.

If there is anyone here to help me and guide me to the solution, I would be very grateful.

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    var mSipProfile: SipProfile? = null
    var username: String? = "..." //I have it correct in my code
    var password: String? = "..." //I have it correct in my code
    var domain: String? = "..." //I have it correct in my code
    var builder: SipProfile.Builder? = SipProfile.Builder(username, domain).setPassword(password)
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/registration"

    private val mSipManager: SipManager? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        SipManager.newInstance(this)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        println("SSSSSTTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        println("CCCCCCCCRRRRRREEEEEEEEEAAAAAAATTTTTTTTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
    }

    private var listenSipSession: SipSession.Listener = object : SipSession.Listener() {
        override fun onRinging(session: SipSession?, caller: SipProfile?, sessionDescription: String?) {
            super.onRinging(session, caller, sessionDescription)
            println("EVVVVVVVOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO GAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        }
    }

    private var listener: SipAudioCall.Listener = object : SipAudioCall.Listener() {

        override fun onCalling(call: SipAudioCall?) {
            super.onCalling(call)
            println("111111 CALLING CALLING CALLING")
        }

        override fun onChanged(call: SipAudioCall?) {
            super.onChanged(call)
            println("CHANGED")
            println(call?.state)
        }

        override fun onError(call: SipAudioCall?, errorCode: Int, errorMessage: String?) {
            super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage)
            println("ERROR ERROR ERROR")
        }

        override fun onRingingBack(call: SipAudioCall?) {
            super.onRingingBack(call)
            println("RINGING BACK")
        }

        /*override fun onRinging(call: SipAudioCall, caller: SipProfile) {
            println("RINGING")
            try {
                call.answerCall(30)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("ERROR 2: $e")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }*/

        override fun onCallEstablished(call: SipAudioCall) {
            println("Call established")
            call.apply {
                startAudio()
                setSpeakerMode(false)
//                toggleMute()
            }
        }

        override fun onRinging(call: SipAudioCall?, caller: SipProfile?) {
            super.onRinging(call, caller)
            println("Ringing")
        }

        override fun onCallEnded(call: SipAudioCall) {
            println("Call ended " + call.state)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        closeLocalProfile()
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.

            mSipProfile = builder?.build()

            val intent = Intent("com.example.softphone.INCOMING_CALL")
            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA)
            mSipManager?.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null)

            if (call.method == "register") {
                val registrationStatus = register()
                result.success(registrationStatus)
            }

            if (call.method == "call") {
                call()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun closeLocalProfile() {
        try {
            mSipManager?.close(mSipProfile?.uriString)
            println("Local profile closed.")
        } catch (ee: Exception) {
            println("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy. Failed to close local profile.")
        }
    }

    ///Method for making call
    private fun call(): String {
        var status = "Unknown"

        try {
            println("Making call")
            status = "In Call"
            val call: SipAudioCall? = mSipManager?.makeAudioCall(
                    mSipProfile?.uriString,
                    "...", //I have it correct in my code
                    listener,
                    30
            )
            println(call)
        } catch (e: SipException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println(e)
        }
        return status
    }

    ///Method for registering user
    private fun register(): String {
        var status = "Unknown"
        try {
            mSipManager?.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile?.uriString, object : SipRegistrationListener {
                override fun onRegistering(localProfileUri: String) {
                    status = "Registering with SIP Server..."
                    println(status)
                }

                override fun onRegistrationDone(localProfileUri: String, expiryTime: Long) {
                    status = "Ready"
                    println(status)
                }

                override fun onRegistrationFailed(
                        localProfileUri: String,
                        errorCode: Int,
                        errorMessage: String
                ) {
                    status = "Registration failed. Please check settings."
                    println(status)
                }
            })
        } catch (e: SipException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println(e)
        }
        return status
    }
}
```

Here is my IncomingCallReceiver class:

```
class IncomingCallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        var incomingCall: SipAudioCall? = null
        try {
            val listener: SipAudioCall.Listener = object : SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                override fun onRinging(call: SipAudioCall, caller: SipProfile) {
                    try {
                        call.answerCall(30)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
            val wtActivity: WalkieTalkieActivity = context as WalkieTalkieActivity
            incomingCall = wtActivity.manager?.takeAudioCall(intent, listener)
            incomingCall?.setListener(listener)
            incomingCall?.answerCall(30)
            incomingCall?.startAudio()
            incomingCall?.setSpeakerMode(true)
            if (incomingCall?.isMuted!!) {
                incomingCall?.toggleMute()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            incomingCall?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my WalkieTalkieActivity class:

```
class WalkieTalkieActivity : Activity(), OnTouchListener {
    var sipAddress: String? = null
    var manager: SipManager? = null
    var me: SipProfile? = null
    var call: SipAudioCall? = null
    
    lateinit var callReceiver: IncomingCallReceiver

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction("com.example.softphone.INCOMING_CALL")
        }
        callReceiver = IncomingCallReceiver()
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter)
    }

    override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.softphone">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="softphone"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution for that, but I am facing another issue while trying to receive calls. Not sure, because I put that project on hold for a while, so I forgot what exactly is the issue

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you got the on-ringing working? I'm quite curios to do this myself too.

Comment: Let me check and I will post whatever I find in the project